# Plotting large equation in mathematica

Tags: graphing-functions, mathematica

I have this rather large equation which needs to be solved with respect to I1 so that I can plot it against X:

-1 - (0.742611 I1 (1/(-(-14 + 16/I2)^2 + (1 - 15/I1 + 16/I2)^2) - (
    30 (1 - 15/I1 + 16/I2))/(
    I1 (-(-14 + 16/I2)^2 + (1 - 15/I1 + 16/I2)^2)^2)) X^1.5)/((1.36- 
    I1) (I1/(-(-14 + 16/I2)^2 + (1 - 15/I1 + 16/I2)^2))^2.5) + (
 0.495074 X^1.5)/((1.36- 
    I1) (I1/(-(-14 + 16/I2)^2 + (1 - 15/I1 + 16/I2)^2))^1.5) + (
 0.495074 I1 X^1.5)/((1.36- 
    I1)^2 (I1/(-(-14 + 16/I2)^2 + (1 - 15/I1 + 16/I2)^2))^1.5)

Mathematica can't solve it using *Solve*  because it is rather complex and therefore I can't plot the solution.

Is there some way I can achieve this, maybe using another program?

I am not sure if my question is really clear so please ask if you need any further info.

Comment: Could you explain where the equation comes from or any particular features?

Comment: What kind of equation?  There's a good chance that Mathematica can solve it numerically, and plot the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we define `equation` as follows:

```
equation=yourBigEquation;
```

Now you can solve it numerically using `NSolve` producing a table of values (I select only $I1\in\mathbb{R}$ here; start from $X=10^{-10}$ because for $X=0$ there're no usable solutions):

```
sol=I1/.Table[NSolve[equation, I1, Reals], {X, 10^-10, 1, 1/500}];
```

And now plot it:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[sol], Joined->True, PlotRange->All, DataRange->{10^-10, 1}]
```

[image: result]

Comment: Very nice! Thanks, I edited now the equation and we have three variables,so now I definitely can't solve it I want to solve it again with respect to I1 so that I can substitute I1 in another equation. I guess this method can't work when we have I1, I2 and X?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want now. Do you have another equation which depends on I1 which is defined by this first equation? You can try to just solve the system of equations like `NSolve[{equation1,equation2},{variable1,variable2}]`.

Comment: Perfect yes that was the answer to my question